# Opening a calendar microformat file in the Win 8.1 calendar app?

Tags: windows-8, calendar, icalendar

When I get a meeting request thru email and that file contains a ICS or vCal file with the actual event or meeting is it possible to open it and have it added to my Win 8.1 Calendar?

I have my Calendar synced to my corporate Exchange server and not Outlook.com.

This seems like a pretty basic thing to do?

Comment: Have you tried opening these files with the Calendar application I know ICS files should be supported at the very least

Comment: Yes have tried. And they aren't.  Seems like a big requirement that was missed.